# I want to understand mining commands. I'm new

Tags: mining-pools, gpu-mining, xmrig

commands to find out if I found a block in the xmrig mining software, I'm lost with too many commands I'm new I want to learn what all the commands that appear in the mining software mean

Comment: Do you mean the commands you can run from within running console app or the configuration options?

Comment: How to know when the miner finds a block.
appears too many accepted share I'm new to mining
I find myself mining in a turtle coin solitary mining pool

Comment: Using a miner like xmrig, you don't know if you mined a block, it's the pool that checks this and the pool does not send a message to the miner to indicate a block was found by the pool.

Comment: When you say "commands that appear in the mining software", do you mean "messages that appear..."? Are you just trying to understand what all the output is you are seeing from xmrig?